# Creating a hierarchy path from JSON

Tags: python, json

Given the JSON below, what would be the best way to create a hierarchical list of "name" for a given "id"? There could be any number of sections in the hierarchy.

For example, providing id "156" would return "Add Storage Devices, Guided Configuration, Configuration"

I've been looking into using `iteritems()`, but could do with some help.

```
 {
    "result": true,
    "sections": [
        {
            "depth": 0,
            "display_order": 1,
            "id": 154,
            "name": "Configuration",
            "parent_id": null,
            "suite_id": 5
        },
        {
            "depth": 1,
            "display_order": 2,
            "id": 155,
            "name": "Guided Configuration",
            "parent_id": 154,
            "suite_id": 5
        },
        {
            "depth": 2,
            "display_order": 3,
            "id": 156,
            "name": "Add Storage Devices",
            "parent_id": 155,
            "suite_id": 5
        },
        {
            "depth": 0,
            "display_order": 4,
            "id": 160,
            "name": "NEW",
            "parent_id": null,
            "suite_id": 5
        },
        {
            "depth": 1,
            "display_order": 5,
            "id": 161,
            "name": "NEWS",
            "parent_id": 160,
            "suite_id": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
def get_path(data, section_id):
    path = []
    while section_id is not None:
        section = next(s for s in data["sections"] if s["id"] == section_id)
        path.append(section["name"])
        section_id = section["parent_id"]
    return ", ".join(path)
```

... which assumes that `data` is the result of `json.loads(json_text)` or similar, and `section_id` is an `int` (which is what you've got for ids in that example JSON).

For your example usage:

```
>>> get_path(data, 156)
u'Add Storage Devices, Guided Configuration, Configuration'
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I changed `path.append(section["name"])` to `path.insert(0, section["name"])` so that the list is reversed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way is to create a dictionary mapping the IDs to names. For example:

```
name_by_id = {}
data = json.loads(the_json_string)
for section in data['sections']:
    name_by_id[section['id']] = section['name']
```

or using dict comprehensions:

```
name_by_id = {section['id']: section['name'] for section in data['sections']}
```

then you can get specific element:

```
>>> name_by_id[156]
... 'Add Storage Devices'
```

or get all IDs:

```
>>> name_by_id.keys()
... [160, 161, 154, 155, 156]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like:

```
def get_name_for_id(id_num, sections):
    cur_depth = -1
    texts = []
    for elem in sections:
        if elem['depth'] < cur_depth:
            del texts[:]
        elif elem['depth'] == cur_depth:
            texts.pop()
        texts.append(elem['name'])
        cur_depth = elem['depth']
        if elem['id'] == id_num:
            return ', '.join(reversed(texts))
```

With your data it returns:

```
In [11]: get_name_for_id(156, data['sections'])
Out[11]: 'Add Storage Devices, Guided Configuration, Configuration'
```

Also it takes into account the hierarchy based on `depth`, thus if in your data the `id` 156 refers to `depth = 0` the result is:

```
In [16]: get_name_for_id(156, data['sections'])
Out[16]: 'Add Storage Devices'
```

If the depth of the id 156 was 1 then the value returned is:

```
In [22]: get_name_for_id(156, data['sections'])
Out[22]: 'Add Storage Devices, Configuration'
```

Basically it considers the trees:

depth 156 = 0     depth 156 = 1      depth 156 = 2

```
 154  156          154                 154
  |                 |                   |
  |                / \                 155
 155             155 156                |
                                       156
```

And it returns the concatenation of the names in the path from the 156 to the root of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want:

```
>>> sections = data['sections']
>>> lookup = {section['id']: section for section in sections}
>>> lookup[None] = {}
>>> for section in sections:
        parent = lookup[section['parent_id']]
        if 'childs' not in parent:
            parent['childs'] = []
        parent['childs'].append(section)

>>> def printRecurse (section, indent = 0):
        if 'childs' in section:
            section['childs'].sort(lambda x: x['display_order'])
            for child in section['childs']:
                print('{}{}: {}'.format('  ' * indent, child['id'], child['name']))
                printRecurse(child, indent + 1)

>>> printRecurse(lookup[None])
154: Configuration
  155: Guided Configuration
    156: Add Storage Devices
160: NEW
  161: NEWS
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do like this. But for this your input should be like. 
Replace `null` with `None` and `true` with `True` in your input dictionary.

```
def filtering(d,id_n):
    names = []        
    while id_n:
        id_n,name=[(sec['parent_id'],sec['name']) for sec in d['sections'] if sec['id'] == id_n][0]
        names.append(name)
    return names

d = {
"result": True,    #making 'true' with 'True'
"sections": [
    {
        "depth": 0,
        "display_order": 1,
        "id": 154,
        "name": "Configuration",
        "parent_id": None,
        "suite_id": 5
    },
    {
        "depth": 1,
        "display_order": 2,
        "id": 155,
        "name": "Guided Configuration",
        "parent_id": 154,
        "suite_id": 5
    },
    {
        "depth": 2,
        "display_order": 3,
        "id": 156,
        "name": "Add Storage Devices",
        "parent_id": 155,
        "suite_id": 5
    },
    {
        "depth": 0,
        "display_order": 4,
        "id": 160,
        "name": "NEW",
        "parent_id": None,
        "suite_id": 5
    },
    {
        "depth": 1,
        "display_order": 5,
        "id": 161,
        "name": "NEWS",
        "parent_id": 160,
        "suite_id": 5
    }
]
```

}

testing the code with given inputs:-

```
id_n = 156
>>> filtering(d,id_n)
['Add Storage Devices', 'Guided Configuration', 'Configuration']
```